# How to remove first char in kotlin string

Tags: android, string, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to make a calculator in Android Studio with Kotlin and I trying to allow users to make numbers negative and positive, but I got only half of it, making number negative, but can't make it so it turns back to positive, for it I need to remove first char in string, someone knows how to do it?

```
var firstNumber: String = ...
if (firstNumber[0] == '-') {
   firstNumber.
}
```

Comment: If you’re making a calculator you should work with Ints, Longs, or BigDecimals, not Strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`substring`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring.html):

```
firstNumber = firstNumber.substring(1);
```

Comment: thanks bro it worked!

Answer (score 18):

You can use drop() of String class to remove first char of string.

```
firstName = firstName.drop(1);
```